# Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [10060]

Tags: php, sockets

I am following [this](https://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/) tutorial here on socket programming.

But I get this 'warning' when running the following script with public IP address.

```
<?php 
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";
echo "<br/>";
//Connect socket to remote server
if(!socket_connect($sock , '8.8.8.8' , 80))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established \n";
echo "<br/>";

$message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";

//Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Message send successfully \n";
```

But when I replace the IP address with my own local IP `127.0.0.1` it works.
Otherwise I get the following warning:

```
Socket created 

Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [10060]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 13
Could not connect: [10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Why am I getting this warning just because of the IP address?

Comment: I think it **is** about the IP address because no server `bind()` to that address. PHP gives you a warning instead of error because that is not enough to shut the server down

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just because the IP Address. If you persists to test the socket with this address. You can let a server bind to that address in order to make your socket work, or you can change the IP to your local one `127.0.0.1`